# Apache not starting in MAMP (but MySQL working) in OSX

Tags: macos, apache, mamp

I've had MAMP working for a few months and recently installed PostgreSQL.  It recommended installing Apache as well, which I did to make sure PostgreSQL worked.  I then uninstalled PostgreSQL and the apache build and tried to restart MAMP.  It fired up the MySQL database (green light) but Apache didn't start.  I uninstalled and reinstalled MAMP only to face the same problem.

Apache doesn't seem to be logging any errors in the MAMP folder, so without any errors to report I'm struggling with where to begin fixing it.  I'm hoping its to do with the fact that I installed another version (and deleted it) that has caused the problem but I'm too inexperienced to know what I've done.

Where might I find any errors if not in the MAMP folder? Not in:

- /Applications/MAMP/Library/logs
- /Applications/MAMP/bin/logs

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Stoping the Apache solved this issue for me, using the command-line:

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

Comment: How did you find this out?

Comment: trial and error - I had the information, that some ports were blocked and so I tried to unblock them

Comment: /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Could not find specified service

Comment: KSPR - that's what I get too. But, I'm on El Capitan. BUT - if I start Apache directly in MAMP with this: "/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl start" It works. So odd.

Comment: This is really helpful to find the cause of the issue as well. For example this didn't work for me but at least the command line returned a response telling me why.

Comment: Worked perfectly in Sierra 10.12.3. @Cage - If you're getting "command not found" you're probably including the $. The actual terminal command is just sudo apachectl stop. The $ just denotes the normal user (as opposed to root user) in a BASH terminal. You don't typically enter the $, it's already there.

Comment: This worked for me on El Capitan 10.11.6. A quick comment to remind folks you may need to clear your browser cache too - I forgot to do so at first and, while Apache started working again after running this command, I was just getting an "It works!" page for localhost. Once the cache was cleared, everything was back to normal.

Comment: Above command failed with this error.
"/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Could not find specified service"
But this command starts Apache server.
"/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl start"

Comment: Pay attention: if you start MAMP Apache with the apachectl start|stop command, you won't get the configurations made in MAMP dashboard (like specific PHP version and so on...). I set PHP 7.0.33 in MAMP configuration, but starting Apache from apachectl, it uses PHP5.4.46

Answer (score 44):

For those of you upgrading to Yosemite there seems to be a bug which I don't really understand but its easily fixed as posted on their twitter account.

> Workaround for the 10.10 Preview 5 bug: Rename the file “envvars” located in '/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin' into “_envvars” (@mamp_en)

Comment: It worked in MAMP pro 3.0.5 in Sierra as well but the answer at top gave me the error "/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Could not find specified service". Thanks for the quick fix.

Answer (score 42):

I had a similar problem and could solve it by starting on the command line the apachectl included in MAMP:

```
$ /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl start
```

which would yield

```
Syntax error on line 427 of /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf:
Invalid command '\xef\xbf\xbc#AllowOverride', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

This error message was nowhere else, not in any log file or system console. (Turns out I had copied a line from a documentation file which had copied some special characters that were not intended for my system - how easy to find is that!)

This is for MAMP 2.0.1, maybe it's handled better in newer versions.

Comment: great answer, check first if httpd.conf is OK. 

I had an error in the file which prevented Apache from starting correctly had nothing to do with mamp

Comment: I'm able to manually start apache like this, but it doesn't give me any errors and MAMP still isn't able to start or stop it.

Comment: Woah! worked for me!
had to use `sudo` for root permissions!

Comment: `$ /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl start`was enough to restart apache.

Comment: (48)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(48)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down

Answer (score 7):

Change the recommended Apache Port from: port 80  to port 81.

Comment: In this case probably your Skype is using port 80. Go to skype advanced settings and change it.

Answer (score 6):

I have been going through all Stackoverflow posts, but no luck. Finally, I came across this:
https://www.speakinginbytes.com/2013/02/mamp-problems/

> **Sometimes Apache is set through MAMP to open a particular folder and that folder no longer exists. If you simple go to MAMP and change that
>   setting through the preferences button you should be able to fix it.**

That did the trick for me. Hopefully it will help someone else!

Comment: In my particular instance I removed all but one host. That did the trick for me. Apparently one or more of my hosts had been deleted since I had rebooted and MAMP did not identify the directory that was missing.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe its because the original apache is on.
Have you tried to see the status ?
You can try this command to stop it "apachectl status" and then restart mamp and see if it works.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old but in case someone else comes across this. I had a typo in my Virtual Host file (/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf) that was causing Apache not to start. It wasn't until I manually tried to start MAMP's version of Apache from the command line (`/Applications/MAMP/bin/startApache.sh`) that I saw the error and was able to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Command line helps for this issue. like the below,

/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl start

/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl stop

Comment: dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
  Expected in: /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libJPEG.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl: line 80: 35578 Trace/BPT trap: 5       $HTTPD -k $ARGV

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. After a lot of frustration about not having a descriptive error message, I realized I could check the "All messages" log under **Applications/Tools/System messages** (or some similar path, as I just translated from my language here). There I found the explanation, which in my case meant that a library link was broken (probably due to the uninstallation of postgres). I fixed this by recreating the link. In my case it meant I had to run the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libpq.5.3.dylib /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib
```

and now it works!

Answer (score 2):

If it has at one point been working fine then I guess something else on your network is currently using the same port for something else.

I had this problem too: in my case I had changed the default MAMP Apache port from 8888 to 80. It worked fine until I installed a web server on another machine on my network and tweaked /etc/hosts on my local machine to include the new server. This meant that port 80 was already in use and MAMP's Apache couldn't start.

The solution was to either stop the second web server on my network, or revert MAMP back to 8888. Both approaches worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

In my case was a wrong ssl certificate on an vhost. To test, just temporarily deactivate ssl from all your ssl vhost and see if it starts. NOTE: even if the ssl vhost are not checked.

Answer (score 2):

1) Quit MAMP

2) Use the command-line to run:

```
$ sudo apachectl restart
```

3) Open MAMP and start Apache

4) Apache should start this time with any luck

---

My situation was that when I used the command-line to run:

```
$ sudo apachectl stop
```

nothing changed. And when I used the command-line to run:

```
$ sudo apachectl start
```

I received the message

```
httpd (pid 600) already running
```

I tried restart instead and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this particular issue, I reinstalled PostgreSQL and the apache build that came with it, then I installed MAMP again and MAMP worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

If your htdocs (or equivalent) folder is stored on external storage, you may need to connect to it (in finder, or using cmd + K) before apache will start.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and it turned out that a .txt file that was not a vhosts file had somehow been saved to my `sites-available` folder that Apache was automatically including, and expected every file to be a vhosts file.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you're not launching an older version of MAMP. This happened to me when using spotlight to find MAMP. When the app upgrades, it keeps older copies around in your Applications folder.